# Connect to SQL server Dialog Box

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I´d like to use "Connect to server" dialog box (this dialog appears at startup in SQL Server Management studio) in my application, which I´m writing in C#. Does anybody know how to add this dialog to C# project or if possible to use it somehow like:

For example:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
```

I cannot find claas which created this connection dialog in C#.
I know, I can create my own dialog box, but why creating something what was created earlier.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can't easily use that because you would be violating the license of SSMS.

Comment: This is part of SQL Server Management Studio application and you can't just get this particular window and use it in your C# app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a simple modal dialog that requies 4 pieces of information (server type, server name, and auth credentials).

There is no such "plug-in" for this.  You'll need to make your own version of it.  It can be as simple as a dialog with a two drop downs (one for server type, one for auth type), and three text boxes.

Or if you're not so interested in the server type, and you are just looking to populate a connection string, you're just looking at 4 text boxes for the user to input the connection parameters.